# A four digit year could not be found Data missing when using protected dates in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

**i am trying to updating ( date_of_completion ) field, but it showing error , if i removed protected $dates from model it works**

**error**

```
A four digit year could not be found
Data missing
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{

    protected $dates = ['date_of_join','date_of_completion','dob'];
    protected $table = 'student_lists';
    protected $fillable = ['student_name', 'student_registration_id', 'date_of_join',    'student_phone_no', 'student_photo','date_of_completion','dob' ];

}
```

**input in view**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<input   type="date" name="date_of_completion" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="date_of_completion"  required>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me the controller section where you edit the date?

Answer (score 0):

All fields added to `$dates` expects the date in the default format, usually `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

You can change the default format like this:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
```

But it will affect all dates. In your case, it's better to cast `date_of_completion` to the desired format:

```
protected $casts = [
    'date_of_completion' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

[See docs here](http://%20https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)